# VMware broke host Wifi connection

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have already seen a lot of questions similar to this one, but none of their solutions worked for me.

My issue is very similar to [this](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/485015).

I bought a new laptop, Lenovo Yoga 15 with Windows 8.1, and have been running VMware with one guest, Ubuntu 14, for a few days with no problem. Then one day after starting it up (out of sleep mode) Windows shows as connected to the VMware network, and the internet does not work. I disabled the adapter it was connected to and everything worked fine again.

Next time I started my computer up, it was the same problem, but this time disabling the adapter did not fix it. When I disabled all the adapters Windows shows the "connections available" icon, but when I try to connect to my home wifi all it says is "Can't connect to the network". I've reset the router, same problem, but I am able to connect to my phone's hotspot wifi network.

I've uninstalled VMware, reinstalled it, did a repair, nothing. I've uninstalled and reinstalled all the network adapters under Device Manager, still nothing.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after struggling a few days with this, somehow a combination of resetting the router and turning off it's password, plus downloading and installing new drivers seemed to do the trick. 
Note - the VMWare virtual adapters are now completely gone, but I still have a network connection in my vm somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Device Manager` and locate your Ethernet adapter, uncheck the following option

[image]

Comment: Sorry no that didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but I fixed it with a bit of fidgeting: go to device manager and open up network adapters ( I’m using WiFi so IDk if that changes anything) double click your WiFi adapter and go to advanced, enable D0 PacketCoalescing and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I was able to resolve the issue by opening the computer BIOS, turning of the Wireless connection and turning it back on.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Workstation installs networking components. These are managed by the Virtual Networking Editor application (VNE). VNE attempts to choose the correct adapter for bridging networking, but can get the choice wrong when you have multiple adapters.

Try running VNE (from VMWare Workstation, it's under Edit | Virtual Network Editor.

In the Bridging Mode, turn off Automatic. Instead, choose the network adapter you use for your internet connection.